# Overloading and Polymorphism

Tags: java, overloading

I wish someone would explain me how this decision was taken. I understand that, the overloaded version is chosen based on the declared type, but why, on the second call, the decision was taken based the runtime type?

```
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Parent polymorphicInstance = new Child();

            TestPolymorphicCall tp = new TestPolymorphicCall();
            tp.doSomething(polymorphicInstance);
            // outputs: Parent: doing something... 

            call(polymorphicInstance);
            // outputs: Child: I'm doing something too 
        }
        public static void call(Parent parent){
            parent.doSomething();
        }
        public static void call(Child child){
            child.doSomething();
        }
    }

    public class Parent {
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("Parent: doing something...");
        }
    }
    public class Child extends Parent{
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("Child: I'm doing something too"); 
        }
    }

    public class TestPolymorphicCall {
        public void doSomething(Parent p) {
            System.out.println("Parent: doing something...");
        }
        public void doSomething(Child c) {
            System.out.println("Child: doing something...");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *Parent* class reference is referring to *Child* class object:

```
Parent polymorphicInstance = new Child();
```

So, when you pass the reference in call method, the actual method invoked is the one with *Parent* parameter type only. But when you  call the method `doSomething()`, on *parent* reference:

```
public static void call(Parent parent){
    parent.doSomething();
}
```

It will call `doSomething()` method, that you have overridden in *Child* class.

---

This is the classic case of *polymorphism*. Suppose you have a class *Shape* and a subclass *Circle*, which overrides the method `calculateArea()` defined in *Shape* class.

```
Shape circle = new Circle();
// This will invoke the method in SubClass.
System.out.println(circle.calculateArea());
```

When you override a super class method in subclass, then the actual method invoked is decided at runtime, based on what actual object your super class reference points to. This is called *Dynamic Dispatch* of method call.

Comment: Thank you, I kind of confuse myself with this tricky example, because the TestPolymorphicCall class methods isn't calling the argument's reference at all. But you're right, regardless the overloaded version of method called, **which is chosen based on the declared type**, when dealing with polymorphic types, the behavior called is the subtype one.